# Is there a taxonomy of disagreement types?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, metaphilosophy

In philosophy, is there any type of taxonomy of types of disagreements? For example, I want students to look at varying takes on a subject. What I want them to focus on is, Why do such smart people disagree? Is it a disagreement about facts? Is it a disagreement about human anthropology (i.e., what motivates human beings, what humans want, or even human "nature")? Is it a disagreement about risk (i.e., we agree on facts, anthropology, etc., but you're willing to take a 30% risk of bad things and I'm only willing to take a 1% chance of the bad thing happening)? Is it a disagreement about what certain words "mean"? Is it a disagreement about the discount rate used to evaluate future events? Is it a disagreement about proper inferences? etc.

I'd love any thoughts on this. Thanks so much.

Comment: See taxonomies of disagreement on [LessWrong](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/f8KsbMXxMt64EbyAz/practical-conflict-resolution-a-taxonomy-of-disagreement) and in [Koczogh's chapter](https://benjamins.com/catalog/slcs.153.06koc). Not a taxonomy but related is [Aumann's agreement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aumann%27s_agreement_theorem): rational agents with common knowledge of each other's beliefs cannot agree to disagree.

Comment: Thanks. I've read the Less Wrong one, which is good, but does not seem to capture everything. Reading Koczogh and Aumann now.

Comment: There are more taxonomies related to types of conflict resolution than origin, and you may find those relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict_management#Orientations_to_conflict It's likely parties involved may disagree on the conflict's origins..

Comment: Rational agents with common knowledge of each other's beliefs *and a common prior* cannot agree to disagree.  The common prior is a major requirement.  Rational agents may still disagree if they have different priors.  Also this is only applicable to Bayesian inference, which is at best an oversimplified ideal of how agents like humans think.  Even probability itself is not necessarily fundamental to thought; it is one useful formalism among many possible useful formalisms.